# Document delete in MongoDB instance

Tags: mongodb

We've been facing issues where quite a lot of documents are getting deleted from our mongodb instance. I've confirmed that it doesnt happen because of our code since we only have the find and replaceOne(with crupdate:true) API's used.

I ran the command db.serverStatus and under the opcounters section i can see that there are 1929 deletes. The mongodb.log doesn't give much information and i dont see anything related to deletion of documents.

Right now ours is a single node mongodb instance and so i think the opLog is not enabled, which would have probably helped in knowing when the deletes took place.

Is there any other way to debug this or is there anything specific in the mongodb.log i should be looking for?

Comment: Erm, looking at the code proved to be helpful. Assuming that your code is working as intended and therefor a persistence technology must be randomly deleting data sounds... ...like an incorrect conclusion. You might want to check wether you have TTL indices set.

Comment: I don't have any TTL indices set. Also the result of the db.serverStatus has a metrics object which has a section like "ttl" : {"deletedDocuments" : NumberLong(0),"passes" : NumberLong(44776)}. Although the description of ttl.deletedDocuments and ttl.passes seem to be contradicting each other in my case. There were no documents deleted but there were 44776 cases where the background process removes documents from collections with a ttl index? Not able to understand this.

Comment: The TTLmonitor runs every minute, regardless wether a TTL index is set or not. It is a default background process.

Comment: OK so then the monitor ran 44776 time in the background and TRIED to remove but since there were no TTL indice set, the ttl.deletedDocuments shows as 0. Hmm still wondering how the documents got deleted.